# ng-repeat not updating information after $scope was updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` which creates a form with some starting data. Then the user is free to modify said data and the changes should appear in the form. Before that, the user submitted data are sanitized by another function, which is called by an `ng-click` on a button.

Everything works well under the hood (I checked my `$scope.some_array`, from which `ng-repeat` takes the data and the new data is in the right place) but nothing happens on the page.

The element:

```
<li ng-repeat="field in some_array" id="field-{{$index}}">
            <div class="{{field.field_color}}">
                <button type="button" ng-click="save_field($index)">done</button>
                {{field.nice_name}}
            </div>
            <div id="field-input-{{$index}}">
                <input type="text" id="{{field.tag}}" value="{{field.content}}">
                <label  for="{{field.tag}}">{{field.nice_name}}</label>
            </div>
  </li>
```

`save_field` code:

```
$scope.save_field = function (index) {
        console.log($scope.some_array[index]["content"])
        var value = $("#field-" + index).children("div").children("input").val()
        var name = $scope.some_array[index]["name"]
        var clean_value = my_clean(value)
        if (norm_value === "") {
            return
        }
        $scope.some_array[index]["content"] = clean_value
        console.log($scope.some_array[index]["content"])
    }
```

On the console I see:

```
10.03.16
10/03/16
```

Which is right, but in the form I only see `10.03.16`. I already tried putting `$timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()})` as the last line of my function, but the output is still the same.

Comment: Get rid of all that jQuery and use angular methodology. Use `ng-model` to bind data to input fields

Comment: try **$scope.$evalAsync(function () { $scope.some_array[index]["content"] = clean_value; });**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use input like this if you want to bind a variable to it. Digest loop will refresh the value but it will not be updated visibly because this is not html native behavior.

Use ng-model instead, it will update view value of the input as expected:

```
<input type="text" id="{{field.tag}}" ng-model="field.content">
```

Also using ng-model your variable will be updated when user modify the input, so you can retrieve it to do some treatments much more easily in save_field function, without jQuery:

```
$scope.save_field = function (index) {
    if (norm_value === "") {
      return;
    }
    $scope.some_array[index]["content"] = my_clean($scope.some_array[index]["content"]);
};
```

More infos: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel